# Equivalent of /dev/nvidia0 for intel?

Tags: graphics

Nvidia video cards have a folder in `/dev` called `nvidia0`. What is the equivalent folder for intel video cards? Running `lspci | grep VGA` reports:

```
Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09).
```

Answer (score 0):

None. Nvidia wants to create the `/dev/video0` or `/dev/nvidia0` for whatever reasons they have (I say that is unhelpful since you have to add yourself to the `video` group to use it). Intel and AMD do not and uses the Linux established methods.

You should ask instead why Nvidia use such separated file instead, which is a mystery.